# Word VBA CustomUI embedding Ribbon in many documents

Tags: xml, vba, ribbon, word-2010

is there an easy way to add the CustomUI xml to many files? I have hundreds of documents which need to be adjusted. Doing it manually would take me a lot of time, also i'd have to redo it if something changes.

I am not allowed to use a template document.

1. Can I embed the CustomUI with VBA into the document?
2. What alternatives do I have to automate this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Open XML SDK to get the job done programmatically for all your documents. Be aware, the SDK supports only open XML documents (.docx). See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Also you may consider developing an add-in which can deliver all UI customizations. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442946.aspx) for more information.